# Comments explaining downvote deleted

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-comments

I commented on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22401090/1070480) in order to explain why I downvoted it. Now I see that the comments have been removed, and the answer remains unchanged.

Why were they removed? Shouldn't I at least be notified that they have been removed?

Comment: No, there is no notification when comments are deleted. And comments explaining votes are not necessary, and are often flagged for removal. Comment on the post if you want, no need to comment on the votes.

Comment: @yivi Okay, I will remove everything that is not constructive criticism. Is there anywhere I can see what I wrote in my deleted comments?

Comment: No, I'm afraid deleted comments go to comment-heaven. Only diamond mods can see them.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye If you deleted it, usually you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @user202729 I'm not sure I follow you. My comments were deleted by somebody else; otherwise there wouldn't have been any problem.

Comment: You should point out if an answer is not per the answering guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer @yivi although they are not necessarily they something that should be done as per the https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down page

Comment: @Martin I do not understand.

Comment: Stack Exchange recommends giving feedback as a comment if something is wrong with an answer or question from https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down `If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.`

Comment: I never said "do not give feedback". I said "give feedback on the **post** (if you want), not on the **vote**".

Comment: `comments explaining votes are not necessary, and are often flagged for removal` this bit is what i have a problem with if you down vote and say why it is commentary on the post normally, i don't know for this example but i don't think it should be recommended to not say why you have downvoted something.

Comment: @Martin Comments on votes are discouraged quite emphatically all around. Comments on content, not so. I can comment on a post and explain why I believe it is poor, and/or I can vote.  These are two separate, independent feedback mechanisms.

Comment: But the downvote penalizes a user without any feedback how are they supposed to know how to improve? It just creates a hostile environment ppl go around downvoting without reason new people are not going to know what they have done wrong and going to feel alienated from the system and it risks making SO an elitist system.

Comment: @Martin this has been discussed ad nauseaum. Search around in meta. And again, nothing stops you from commenting on a post you vote. Simply, no need to comment the vote. E.g. _"This answer is wrong because snakes are not mammals"_ is different from _"I downvoted you because you state that a snake is a mammal"_.

Comment: yeah, they are different one explicitly states I downvoted you for ... the other does not allowing people to choose to inform of the problem, so following on if an answer or question has no comments on it what is the purpose of the downvote system, how is it going to help the user improve? it just seems downvoting without a reason feels more hostile than supporting improvements

Comment: @MartinBarker Implying that downvotes were made without a reason is, in turn, not reasonable. We have well established reasons why [providing feedback on downvotes is not mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251). Coupled with the fact that we cannot read minds, you are always better off assuming first that there might be a problem with the voted content. Else, just ignore it and let it go as another case of [Tim losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/282465).

Comment: @Martin Votes are not a teaching tool to help posters "learn from their mistakes". It's a rating and curation mechanism intended to help _future readers_. Again, nothing is stoping anyone from making comments on a post quality, which of course help everybody (the poster and future visitors).

Comment: Then the Ask a Question Blocking system needs removing because new users end up with negative no way of knowing why, then get blocked from asking questions again, and end up like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380917/is-there-any-way-to-improve-this-question .  This very question has at least 2 downvotes on it, and  It's clear as to what the OP is asking it does not require research because it's a discussion. so why have there been downvotes?

Comment: @MartinBarker There are *innumerable* resources on how to ask good questions.  There's tons of info in the help center, in posts here on meta, and the internet at large, on what makes a good or a bad question.  People don't need others to hold their hand though the process of asking a question in order to know basic things like that their question should be clear, have enough information to answer it, that they should be doing their research before asking, etc.  And  you absolutely need to do your research before starting a discussion on a topic?  Why would you think you wouldn't?

Comment: @Servy Oh I'm sorry, I'm from England and apparently, I don't know the mean of a discussion Let go by Meta's definition shall we "A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective." Subjective means not Factual meaning research is pointless because it won't be research it will be opinions and they are inherently not fact and therefore not valid research.

Comment: @Martin, one possible reason to downvote a question is "I do not find this question useful". How would that comment be particularly helpful for someone asking a question?

Comment: @yivi but it's not for that, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" that does not mean 'i did not find it useful' it's supposed to mean that it's not useful for the community, otherwise I should go round downvoting every question that is in a programming lang I don't use because I don't find it useful., so you have just highlighted how it's being commonly misused

Comment: @Martin, you are free to use your votes as you see fit. Me, I interpret that guidance as _"I do not find this question useful for future visitors"_.

Comment: @MartinBarker Just because a question doesn't have an objectively correct answer doesn't mean no facts are ever relevant to it.  Most good discussions, particularly here, will *absolutely* involve knowing and sharing facts.  But more importantly, research is more than just "coming up with facts to support one's arguments", despite how important that is in a good discussion question.  It also means things like looking up past discussions on the topic and seeing the arguments and conclusions of it, else you see cases like the poor question that's just repeating information.

Comment: Ok I'm done because I'm gonna lose my temper as contradictory statements 'I interpret that guidance as "I do not find this question useful for future visitors"' and yet also said in the same comment chain "Coupled with the fact that we cannot read minds," so what you can read the minds of all future visitors but not of the current users you see the hypocrisy and how that can be seen as elitist?

Comment: @Martin if you are losing your temper, better to call it quits. No reason to get angry though, this is just a discussion and no one is attacking anyone. Well, you seem to be calling me an elitist hypocrite, but I chose not to take it personally. I think you are another fine user, just like myself, even if you happen to disagree with me on this.

Comment: Regarding the bit about "reading future visitors minds": I'm judging content when I vote, and I can make a judgement about usefulness without reading minds. E.g. the hypothetical questions _"What's better, Java or GO?"_ or _"How to concatenate a string in Perl?"_, I can judge them _unuseful_ on their own, because of my own opinion and experience on what a useful question would be on this site. The comment about mind-reading wasn't mine anyway, and referenced a completely different thing.

Comment: @MartinBarker: "*Subjective means not Factual meaning research is pointless because it won't be research it will be opinions and they are inherently not fact and therefore not valid research.*" Not all opinions are equal or equally valid. Opinions can be informed or uninformed. The latter are not useful.

Comment: @MartinBarker: At the end of the day, telling someone what's wrong with their post does not need to be prefaced with "I downvoted because...". If you feel the need to explain something that can be fixed about their post, do so. But don't do it in the context of your voting pattern; do it in the context of explaining what's wrong.

Comment: You can vote on posts, and you can comment on posts, but please don't comment on your votes. Such voting explanation comments are purely noise and serve only to stir up flame wars and butthurt.

Comment: @tiw its not unnecessary, its actively harmful to comment on your votes. It is most harmful to your cause, as the recipient is much less likely to heed your advice if you start off your comment by telling them that you downvoted their post. There is literally no good that can ever come from commenting on your votes. If you think a post can be improved, leave a comment stating that, but don't broadcast your voting history with it.

Comment: @Tiw That is just the usual dichotomy. Naturally, askers and answerers want to be given explanations when they receive a downvote. Curators, who understand the scale of the problem and do not want to become a target, will usually side on the latter case.

Comment: Summary here is, comments pointing out problems with the post are fine, but (1) avoid calling attention to the fact that you voted one way or another, and (2) avoid saying anything unnecessarily aggressive or hostile. Note that (1) is a special case of (2). In this case, as Yvette pointed out, things like *"Did you think through this code at all before suggesting it?"* are needlessly hostile, and actually convey no useful information. I would have probably selectively deleted rude portions of your comment, rather than removing the whole thing, but most moderators won't bother with that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I deleted your comments, there were flags on two of them and this is what it looks like to give a perspective of why I deleted them.

[image]
[image]

This borders on harassment. The "AP" (answer poster - I'm hoping it takes off), saw your comments and there's no real point leaving a monologue of comments that are triple the length of the answer.

> Did you think this code through at all before suggesting it?  ...

This is rude.

I'm officially (as a moderator) asking you to stop commenting on the answer.

As for giving people notifications when a comment is deleted. I have deleted a total of 2.5k comments on meta and 69.7k comment on main. This is one moderator of a large moderation team. It is untenable to notify people when their comments are deleted. It's unnecessary noise to an already busy site.

Comment: Ugh, mouse cursor in the screenshots. The cursor lives to fight another day.

Comment: Use firefox... They have cookies! (And a button to easily get screenshots of pages)

Comment: @Braiam I will explore that. It's the large scale font sizing on my mac that's doing it. Playing havoc with screenshots.

Comment: *move comments to code review.se* is not a feature, right?

Comment: @rene you know code review shudders even when we make jokes like this, right?

Comment: Did they actually post the exact same comment multiple times or is there just overlap from having to do this in multiple images?

Comment: @BSMP: Yes. The last pair of identical comments were posted within minutes of each other (presumably), but were deleted at least an hour apart.

Comment: *"It's the large scale font sizing on my mac that's doing it."* Why don't you just lower the resolution? That is, after all, the whole point of a Retina display. Scaling the entire screen by changing the resolution is much more application-friendly than scaling just the font. The same is true in Windows: you are better off lowering the resolution and keeping the DPI scaling set to 100% than you are trying to increase the DPI scaling, since that causes all kinds of app-compatibility problems and general ugliness. It shouldn't, mind you, but too many apps don't scale properly because history.

Comment: Regarding the content of the answer, I think the screenshots you show are rather misleading, as they include comments deleted by the CP (comment poster; hoping it won't catch on). It would make more sense to just show the comments that the CP *intended* to be visible, which were the same ones that were flagged and deleted. Plenty of people make errors in comments and delete them to start over, not realizing that moderators actually see full comment histories. I really don't think there was any intent of abuse going on with respect to deleted comments.

Comment: I think @BSMP would like to hear about Cody last comment.

Comment: @cody I don't just scale the font.  The comment was made to point out i use blind as a bat resolution  :) As for the history the times of posting and deletion and who deleted are all there for that reason.  Also the AP is notified every time a comment is written

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't really have anything to add, just replying to your comment so I get to be a CR.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I agree the first two comments you deleted were a bit rude—that was unnecessary of me, and why I removed those parts when I added the comments back later on.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Be mindful, every time you post a comment under a post, that person is notified, even if you're deleting them, if the person is online, they will see a plethora of comment notifications. Plus they flagged your comments, they weren't appreciating. Sometimes, less is more.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Hm, okay. I'm sorry for that outcome, and I didn't see that they had been flagged (otherwise I wouldn't have added them back after you removed them). The reason I deleted the comments and started over is that a comment can only be edited for a limited time (which is understandable if it is in the middle of a conversation, but perhaps doesn't make sense for all comments) and after that you can't access the markdown (which I often use quite a lot), which can be circumvented in this way. But yes, I do see that repeated commenting and deleting can be unappreciated for that reason.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye you can't see that they've been flagged, only moderators can, which is why they were deleted. So if your comments have been deleted, there's a good chance they were flagged first. Mods generally only go deleting things when they've been flagged.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Okay, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @CodyGray  Does *full comment histories* include edit history? I'm wondering that there're five minutes of edit-allow time, and many will change their comment during the 5 minutes, maybe those changes will lead to some misunderstandings.

Comment: Yes, @Tiw. Moderators can see all changes to comments. That includes those made during the user during the 5 minute grace period, and changes made by moderators at any time. So yeah, if there's some kind of funny business going on, we aren't going to be fooled. Rest assured though that this really doesn't ever happen.

Comment: No, edits aren't relevant (or shown) here, @Tiw. Just *deleted* comments. You know how you can post a comment, and then immediately delete it to try again? Moderators see all the deleted comments, including self-deleted and mod-deleted comments. That's what happened here. That's why you see all the repetition (duplicates).

Comment: No, @Tiw, those numbers are from a user-script that shows the flags on comments. The orange box means a comment was flagged. The number inside the orange box is the number of flags that were raised on it. This isn't a normal part of the mod display, but there is a user-script that can extract this information from where it is buried and display it inline.